# recover site collection database or restore a site collection

Tags: restore

Is there any way to recover a database or site collection that has been overwritten?

I had a testing site and I was developing bunch of stuff on that site. A co-worker restore an old backup on the current site and now my all developments are gone. Since it's testing site we dont backup. Any ideas ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you have a local copy.

You might be able to have a DBA roll back all the transaction logs if they are around, but without backups and local copies, you might be hosed.

Comment: We have the transaction logs. DBA thinks you can't roll back all the transactions that goes back to 05/20/2013. Could you please enlighten me?